# download files from remote server using git protocol

Tags: git, git-daemon

is it possible to download files from a remote server running `git-daemon`?

or how to download files from `git://` server like downloading files using `curl` from `http://` server?

the server is running this command:

```
/usr/bin/git daemon --reuseaddr --port=1234 --base-path=/home/user1/ --export-all
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download *objects*, using the Git protocol.  Objects are not files: some objects are commit objects, some objects are tree objects, and some objects are blob objects, and if you put all three of these together into a database, you can use that to *extract* files.  But once you write code to do this, you're implementing `git clone` or—best case—`git archive`, so why not use those directly?

Comment: my purpose is to download some untracked files in the working directory without installing an ftp or http server

Comment: Untracked files aren't stored in Git. You cannot get those using Git, which only works with committed stuff, since Git is about commits (not files).